# React router (w/ redux) not updating routing

Tags: react-router, react-router-redux

I'm updating the dependencies of my React project (react router 4, react-router-redux 5 alpha).

My code looks like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <HashRouter>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/report-type/:reportType/:rootAddress' component={App}/>
            <Route component={App}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

it works fine on my local machine but fails to do the routing on the server. I can see that the action `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` fails to update the `routing` key in the next state. I get `location: null` which should be an object instead.

What could be the difference between the two environment that prevents it from working on the server?